# Windows GPO Youtube restricted mode not applied in the browser on some machines

Tags: windows, group-policy, google-chrome, windows-server-2022, restrictions

I have created a group policy to set youtube restricted mode in Edge and Chrome on a Windows server 2022 domain controller. On my test machine (W10 Pro ENG) the policies are applied and seem to work when browsing to https://www.youtube.com/check_content_restrictions. The site reports: **HTTP header restrictions are ON**.

However when I add another machine to the domain (W10 Pro NL) I can see that the policies are applied in Edge and Chrome (`chrome://policy`) but when I browse to https://www.youtube.com/check_content_restrictions. The site reports: **HTTP header restrictions are OFF**.

I can see that the policies are on the machine but they are not applied in the browser (Edge and Chrome).

Do only difference between the machines is the language of Windows 10 (Dutch vs English). This shouldn't have an effect on the policies right?

To test this I added another W10 Pro ENG machine to the domain. Again policies are shown in the browser using `edge://policy` and `chrome://policy` and also https://www.youtube.com/check_content_restrictions reports: **HTTP header restrictions are ON**

Any ideas why the browsers respect the policies only on some machines and not on others?
Are group policies language specific?

All machines are running:

- Windows 10 Pro 22H2 (19045.2006)
- Google Chrome 112.0.5615.50 (64 bit)

Comment: Shouldn’t have any effect, but still worth checking: do you have the Dutch ADML files in your group policy central store?

Comment: Are browsers on all machines using the same version?

Comment: @SamErde: Added Dutch ADML files to the nl-NL folder in PolicyDefinitions and updated the policies on the machines, but no effect. All browsers have the same version (chrome 112.0.5615.50)